# Add unit of measurement to magento front end

Tags: magento, units-of-measurement

I would like to add a unit of measurement to my magento front end additional information. At the moment it is currently:

- Length: 34
- Height: 50
- Weight: 13

The customer has no idea if it is centimeters or meters etc.

How can I change it to:
- Length: 34cm
- Height: 50cm
- Weight: 13g

or

- Length (cm): 34
- Height (cm): 50
- Weight (grams): 13

The first option is preferable.

This is the URL to an example:
http://creativeinfusion.com.au/shop/beaded-square-offering-box-xsmall-black-red-green-flowers-2248

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already know that attribute Unit is fixed. you can change attribute label from Manage Attribute Section in admin like:

```
Length ==  Length (cm)
Height ==  Height (cm)
Weight ==  Weight (grams)
```

if you want in this format -  Length: 34cm - Height: 50cm - Weight: 13g

For this In current theme you have to edit template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml file.
In Attribute file pls replace the following code:

```
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data):

        switch($_data['code']) {
            case 'height':
            case 'length':
                $value = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']).'cm';
            break;      
            case 'weight':          
                $value = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']).'g';
            break;
            default:            
                $value = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']);
            break;              
        }
    ?>
        <tr>
            <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
            <td class="data"><?php echo $value; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Please Check sure you have used same code for attribute, or change accordinlgy.

Hope this help !!

Comment: Thanks @Pankaj, I can now see how to change it in the "Manage Label Options" in the Admin. This might be ok but I think my client will want it like this: Length: 34cm. What would I need to edit in template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml to get this result